# sklearn DBSCAN "cosine" vs "precomputed"

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to compare 2 different DBSCAN clusterings on a simple use case. 
 1/ In one case, I use the cosine metrics of DBSCAN

 2/ In anohter case, I use a precomputed distance matrix using cosine similarity 
My problem is that I don't have the same results for the 2 approaches. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? 

 Here is some code sample

```
def cluster(X, metric="cosine"):
    cluster = DBSCAN(
        eps=0.5,
        min_samples=3,
        metric=metric,
        algorithm="brute"
    )

    cluster.fit_predict(X)

    return cluster

sentences = [
    "annuler ma commande",
    "commande à annuler",
    "merci de bien vouloir annuler ma commande",
    "produits cassés",
    "mes produits sont cassés",
    "ma commande de produits cassés"
]

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
tfidfs = vectorizer.fit_transform(sentences)
distance_matrix = linear_kernel(tfidfs, tfidfs)

doc_id_to_cluster_1 = cluster(tfidfs, "cosine").labels_
doc_id_to_cluster_2 = cluster(sparse.csr_matrix(distance_matrix), "precomputed").labels_
```

doc_id_to_cluster_1 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
doc_id_to_cluster_2 = [0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0]

 
I was expecting to have the same results.

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing to computing your distance with the cosine metric directly and you should get what you expect.

```
>>> from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances
>>> distance_matrix = pairwise_distances(tfidfs, tfidfs, metric='cosine')

>>> print(cluster(tfidfs, "cosine").labels_)
>>> print(cluster(sparse.csr_matrix(distance_matrix), "precomputed").labels_)
[0 0 0 1 1 1]
[0 0 0 1 1 1]
```

The linear kernel and cosine distance are close mathematically but the linear kernel will give 1 for full similarity, whereas a cosine distance for full similarity is 0, so 
`linear_kernel(tfidfs, tfidfs)` is equal to  `1 - pairwise_distances(tfidfs, tfidfs, metric='cosine')`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! It worked exactly as expected!